# How to make my gallery as expected?

Tags: theming, 8

I created a content type named 'Book page with Gallery'.
It has a standard 'Body' field and a 'Gallery' field which type is Image (Allowed number of values: unlimited).
And by default, I get this:
[image]
I tried to add some CSS to have the pictures "floating left" (field__item being the class of the div containing the picture):

```
.field__item {
  float: left;
  margin: 0 10px 5px 0;
}
```

And it works!
But it works too well
[image]
As you can see, the Book navigation items float too :-(
How can I do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I made it work.
With the help of someone who put me in the good direction (his comment has been removed, Why?)

```
.field__item:last-child { float: none; !important; }
```